# Pattern for reading from a transport in Twisted Python

Tags: python, twisted

In Twisted Python, data is written to a Protocol's transport, but received by overwriting the dataReceived method. Is there a pattern for reading from a transport? This would be helpful when implementing state using `inlineCallbacks`

For example:

```
class SomeProtocol(Protocol):
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def login(self):
        self.transport.write('login')
        resp = yield self.transport.read(5, timeout=1) # this doesn't exist
        if resp != 'user:':
            raise SomeException()
        self.transport.write('admin')
        resp = transport.read(9, timeout=1)
        if resp != 'password:':
            raise SomeException()
        self.transport.write('hunter2')
        # ... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been a couple attempts at implementing APIs like this one over the years.  None have gained any traction.  I think they've all been abandoned at this point.

In principle, this isn't difficult to implement.  You're just transforming the dataReceived callback - a push-style API - into a pull-style API.

In practice, the resulting code is fragile and tends to contain more bugs.

I think the problem you're trying to address is that `dataReceived` is a very low-level primitive for parsing a stream of bytes.

There are a number of possible solutions to this.  You could try building a higher level protocol-based tool which knows about aspects of your protocol (this is basically what all of the protocol implementations in Twisted do).  You could also look at such third-party libraries as [tubes](https://github.com/twisted/tubes) (which provides a different abstraction for dealing with byte streams).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up maintaining a list of deferreds to callback as data arrives, and buffering the incoming data until it satisfies the length of data required for the first deferred in the list.

```
class SomeProtocol(Protocol):

    # initialise self.buf and self.readers in __init__

    def deferred_read(self, count, timeout=None):
        """Return a deferred that fires when data becomes available"""
        d = defer.Deferred()
        reader = [d, count]
        timeout_cb = None
        if timeout is not None:
            timeout_cb = self.reactor.callLater(timeout, self.deferred_read_timeout, reader)
        reader.append(timeout_cb)
        self.readers.append(reader)
        self.check_readers()
        return d

    def deferred_read_timeout(self, reader):
        """Timeout this reader and check if others now match"""
        d, count, timeout_cb = reader
        self.readers.remove(reader)
        d.errback(TimeoutException()) # defined elsewhere
        self.check_readers()

    def check_readers(self):
        """Check if there is enough data to satisfy first reader"""
        try:
            while 1:
                reader = self.readers[0]
                d, count, timeout_cb = reader
                if len(self.buf) < count:
                    break
                data = self.buf[:count]
                self.buf = self.buf[count:]
                self.readers.remove(reader)
                try:
                    timeout_cb.cancel()
                except: pass
                d.callback(data)
        except IndexError: pass

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.buf += data
        self.check_readers()
```

It currently requires count to be non-zero. It would be good to extend it to support returning whatever is currently in the read buffer, and reading with a timeout but no count so that whatever is in the buffer after the timeout is returned.

Comment: This is several years old, but I would just like to point out that this is like using a hammer to try and unscrew a fitted pipe.  If there really is a large amount of time in between sending and receiving, then it may be justified, but typically you shouldn't use an asynchronous protocol when you need synchronous read/writes.  That is, when the returned data is not self-identifying, synchronous communication should be preferred over asynchronous communication.  Just because you're using twisted does not mean that everything needs to be based around the reactor...

Comment: @AlexBaum I'm curious how you would implement synchronous reads in Twisted without blocking the reactor? Do you have an example?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the twisted architecture at all.  That's how.  That's not to say that the reactor isn't useful, but I've found over the past couple of years that the twisted reactor, for all the good it does, does a lot of evil as well.  The two biggest evils I've found are that it forces you to use quite a bit of setup in order to perform a unit test, which deters the majority of users from actually writing them.  The second is hiding stack trace through the use of callLaters and deferreds.  If you'd like me to provide an example of a synchronous non-twisted TCP client I can.

Comment: The question was about a pattern for fitting this into Twisted because it's part of a larger system - I agree if you were just doing this one task then it's more suited to a synchronous environment. I really enjoy using `trail` for testing though, in particular being able to control the clock is really powerful for our work. It's probably a matter of the right tool for the job.